# Comparing text files for equality

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, nsstring

I just want to know if one text file equal to another. Of course I can load files to NSString and compare them, but is there a better way?

Comment: you could check file size first using [NSFileManager fileSsystemAttributesAtPath] - if the same, then compare contents

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the **NSFileManager documentation**. There is a method which will complete your task I think:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr contentsEqualAtPath: @"/path/to/file1.txt" andPath: @"/path/to/file2.txt"] == YES) {
    //MATCH
}
```